# GR visualization

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, geodesics

I'm watching some GR lectures by Schuller (more or less rushing through them so bear with my ignorance here please) in [Lecture 10: Metric Manifolds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONCZNwKswn4&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&index=10).

He's talking about geodesics in a manifold with a metric and that you can basically require the geodesics to be straight lines for a person living in this manifold. So from a metric you derive a covariant derivative.

Let's talk about some $2$-dimensional person living in a $2$-Sphere 
  (FIG.$1$)

[image]

I suppose this person couldn't see the mountain, so he would just see something like a reparameterization. I've indicated two possible geodesics  as arrows. (FIG.$2$)

Now when we require the geodesics to be the straight lines does the manifold get deformed or do the coordinate charts get twisted? And do the two geodesics become one since they both start at the same point and end at the same point and go the same distance?

Comment: What are figures 2 and 3 supposed to represent?

Comment: The region around the bulge not directly as seen from the person in the manifold but supposed to be like that before and after the requirement that the geodesics be straight lines.

Comment: The lines are only "straight" if you look at a small segment of them. Do you understand that?  It's like how a one-term Taylor series is a good approximation only if you stay near the point where you expanded it.  I think your Fig. 3 suggest that you think there's some "straightening" process?  If so, that's wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that you literally take the geodesic and straighten it out by either deforming the manifold or the coordinate charts or something.. So that's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the geodesic.  There's no physical process of "straightening."  The geodesics are extrema of distance - usually shortest distance - between two points on the manifold.  That's the generalization of "straight" in a general manifold.

If you think of the Earth as a perfect sphere and find the shortest distance between two points on that, it will look "curved" as viewed from space, where you're out of the 2D manifold of the Earth's surface.  If you are on the surface and only look in a nearby neighborhood of your current location, it will appear straight.  You can even put down a Cartesian grid over it that will work as long as you stay "close enough" to the origin.  If you get far away from the origin, it will have pathologies in the form of coordinate singularities, like were all the line of longitude come together at the poles.

Roughly speaking this is like a Taylor series situation.  You can approximate a smooth function by its first derivative, but the quality of that approximation gets bad - even unusable - once you get "far" from the point where you did the Taylor expansion.

Comment: So it is like if i go along the curve and only look really close nearby it is straight and when i go to the next "point" along the curve and I look really close by it is straight if i use the covariant derivative with the L.C. connection again etc..?

Comment: Something like that, yes.  But other curves will also have that property.  The thing that makes the geodesic special is that it's also an extrema of length between points.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understand much better now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first think how we identify a curve in our space as being straight (or approximately so): we could say that it realizes the shortest curve connecting any two point on it, or that it connects a light ray connecting any two points (i.e. if you look in its direction from it start point, you just see a point), or you could say that its tangent vector has the same direction everywhere.

These concepts can all be generalized to Riemannian (or semi-Riemannian) manifolds, in all cases they give the concept of a geodesic. If you think of other ways that we would identify a curve as being a straight line, probably that will also generalize to that curve being a geodesic.

What this means is that when you encounter a geodesic in the Riemannian manifold in which you live, for all you know it is a straight line. (Note that you *can* identify from within your space that the geometry is not Euclidean, that is a different notion).

You don't change anything in your manifold, or in your coordinate charts, though there is a special class of coordinates that may be interesting, namely the [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates): at every point there is a neighbourhood on which the coordinates are Euclidean up to first order, and geodesics in the manifold through your point correspond to straight lines.